# How pass variables between pages in symfony 1.4?

Tags: symfony-1.4

I want to pass a variable between pages but do not change every link for that. Is there a way to do that - pass variables between templates and actions. Do  not need to keep it in session. In url ony.

Answer (score 1):

You can use URL parameters which which can be accessed by each action and in templates. Although this is often better done using Session storage.

URL parameters:

```
http://www.example.com/something?value=[some value]
```

Then in the action you can access using `$request->getParameter('value')` and in the template using `$sf_param->get('value')`. Keep in mind that you can pass variables from the action to relevant template using the `$this->value` variable which can accessed in template by `$value`.

Then you just adjust the buttons/links in the template to have a different value of the parameter `value` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by include_partial('partial_name',array('variable_name'=>'variable_value'))